# Double integral related to zeta function

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Prove that 
$$\int  _1^{\infty }\int _1^{\infty }\left(\frac{\log \left(\frac{(x+1) y}{(y+1)x}\right)}{x-y}\right)^2dydx=\frac{1}{6} \left(\pi ^2 \log (4)-9 \zeta (3)\right)$$

Comment: Please add your attempts / some context explaining the reason for this identity to be interesting.

Comment: What techniques do you know for managing logarithmic integrals? Are you familiar with differentiation under the integral sign?

Comment: That can also be written as $$\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1+y)\right)^2}{(y-x)^2}\,dx\,dy=2\iint_{0\leq y\leq x\leq 1}\frac{\left(\log(1+x)-\log(1+y)\right)^2}{(y-x)^2}\,dx\,dy$$ and directly converted into an Euler sum by exploiting the Taylor series of $\log(1+z)$ and $\log^2(1+z)$.

Comment: I will be glad to provide and improve my answer, once you improve your question. PSQs (questions just asking *prove that* or *show this*) are not well-received here.

Comment: That's fine. I got what you mean.

Comment: A change of variable u=f(x,y), v=g(x,y) would probably permit to get a product of  one dimension well-known integrals.